# Spring EL in PreAuthorize: Use of "this" instead of "@myBean"?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-el

I want to secure my MVC Controller with Spring Method Security the following way :

```
@Controller
public class MyBean {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myUrl", method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    @PreAuthorize("@myBean.isAccessible()")
    public ModelAndView doSomething(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
    }

    public boolean isAccessible() {
        if (...) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there a chance to replace `@myAction` by a reference to `this` ?

Comment: is it just for syntax preferences or do you expect any change in the behavior ?

Comment: Only for syntax preferences - same behaviour.

Comment: It would be easier to maintain f.e. in the case of refactoring the class name.